# add variable id in script tags using grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-plugins, gruntfile, grunt-html-build

I have around 10 files for eg: file1.html, file2.html, fil31.html, file4.html

Each file contains a starting and end script tag with blank id='' field

I want to add id's to all the script tags in each file.

The id's are the file names.

```
before running grunt
eg: file1.html

<script type='text/ng-template' id=''>
     <div>Couple of other dive tags</div>
</script>

after running grunt the id filed should have an if which is the file name

eg: file1.html

<script type='text/ng-template' id='file1.html'>
     <div>Couple of other dive tags</div>
</script>
```

I have tried it by using couple grunt packages but can't get my head around how to make them pick file name and add them as ids.

```
grunt file_append
grunt-script-link-tags
```

Has anyone faced the same problem or knows how to solve this?

Comment: Are you on a pur HTML project? Did you took a look to a JS/HTML templating like nunjucks https://github.com/vitkarpov/grunt-nunjucks-2-html/?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to add id's dynamically in the script tag.

[Replace all the text with specified replacement using grunt replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662570/replace-all-the-text-with-specified-replacement-using-grunt-replace)