# Replace all the text with specified replacement using grunt replace

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a .html file which contains id="fixedtext", I want to replace all these id with id="uniquetext"

the grunt-text-replace just replaces the first id it finds and doesnot parse the entire text.

Any idea how can I make either grunt-text-replace https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace

or 
grunt-replace https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace 
to do this for the entire document and not just for the first occurrence.

```
replace: {
            dist: {
                options:{
                    patterns:[{
                        match:'id="fixedtext"',
                        replacement: 'id="'+something[i++] +'"'
                    }],
                    files:[
                        {
                            expand: true,
                            src:['./source.html'],
                            dest:'./dest.html'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: As far I have researched adding a unique id the id field of script field is not possible from the following approach. Grunt task some how caches the task and uses it even when the task is called recursively.

Answer (score 0):

this is what can be done if unique ids are to be added. 
Assuming that you already have an array of all the id you want to add when you run your task.

In this case the id's are the file names

create your own wrapper task

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

    grunt.initconfig({
    wrap:{
            html:{
                header:'<script type="text/ng-template" ',
                footer:'</script>',
                src:'./yourPathToFile/',
                dest'./yourPathToDest/'
            }
        }
    });

grunt.registerMultiTask('wrap', 'wrap header and footer with custom id', function(){
 var data = this.data;
 getListOfFiles(data.src);

 function getListOfFiles(expand_path){
       var listOfFiles = fs.readdirSync(expand_path);
            for(var i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++){
                var completePath = expand_path + listOfFiles[i];
                var extension = path.extname(completePath);
                if(fs.lstatSync(completePath).isDirectory()){
                    var newDirPath = completePath + '/';
                    console.log('true------ : \n',newDirPath);
                    getListofFiles(newDirPath);
                }
                else if(extension == '.html'){
                    console.log('F:\n', completePath);
                    fullSrcPath = path.resolve(completePath);
                    content = grunt.file.read(fullSrcPath);
                    scriptId = 'id="' + listOfFiles[i]+'">';
                    header = (grunt.template.process(data.header));
                    footer = (grunt.template.process(data.footer));
                    wholeFile = header + scriptId + content + footer;
                    grunt.file.write(fullSrcPath, wholeFile);
                }
            } 
 }

});
```